# Make reference to a section of my wiki

Tags: github, markdown, wiki

I am working on a Wiki on GitHub and I'd like to use references to tell the user to go to an specific section of my wiki in case he/she wants to consult something.

For example

```
If you want to know more about this, go to **Section 2**


##Section 2
Some text
```

My intention is that if the user clicks on **Section 2** he can immediately see what is on the Section 2. Like a link that leads to a section on the same wiki.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each section anchor name is generated based on the section name, with hyphen between each word (lower case).  For example, in https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki#what-is-hystrix, you can hover over the `chain icon` beside the section name to take a peek at the anchor name (in this case, `#what-is-hystrix`):

[image: Link icon in section heading]

To make reference to it:

```
[Go to section](#what-is-hystrix)
```

Comment: Do you have any idea of why isn't it working? 

`Go to [Example](###1.4-Example)`

Comment: Try: [Example](#14-example)
(no dot, and all lowercase)

Comment: `[3.1.5 Modifying Files](###315-modifying-files)`

Not working :(

Comment: Too many `#` in your link, should be:
[3.1.5 Modifying Files](#315-modifying-files)

Comment: I tried with only one. I don't know why isn't it working :(

Comment: Perhaps you can share the link to your github wiki?  For your reference, [this is a sample working markdown](https://gist.github.com/ibmkendrick/2d09c9cd087b76e04fd7c307216bda7f).

Comment: I think I know what's going on. The link I'm trying to reference has characters such as - , ( ). I have tried without them and it works. Do you know what do I have to do in order to be able to use these characters?

Comment: If you hover over the chain icon beside the section header, you can see what the URL is.  The text after the `#` sign (including the `#` sign) is the anchor link you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
If you want to know more about this, go to **[Section 2](#section-2)**

## Section 2
Some text
```

See example: https://gist.github.com/plu/22e4dfdc9e4dab16dd932b675af15aa6

Comment: Do you have any idea of why isn't it working?

`Go to [Example](###1.4-Example)`

Answer (score 0):

Just using:

```
- [Topic](#topic)
```

and for the title

```
## Topic
```

That's ok, [click here for see an example](https://github.com/albertocerqueira/web-plugins-js).